# How to concat a column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, concatenation

I do have a table scenario in SQL Server 2012 that allows me to concat a column from its properties "computed column specification" especially when creating a new record where my table has the following columns design format

```
[VIndex] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
[VISTORID] AS (concat('PD', str([VIndex], len([VIndex]), (0)))) PERSISTED NOT NULL
```

In which case when the `Vindex` auto increments, the `vistorId` column will pick that information and add characters to it to create another unique id

For example

```
VIndex  VISTORID
  1     PD0001
  2     PD0002
  3     PD0003
  4     PD0004
```

The problem am having is in SQL Server 2008, under column properties the "computed column specification" does not allow or recognize `concat`. I have completely run out of ideas, when I script this database to SQL Server 2008, it won't accept so any table having this property is dropped.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Use `+` and make sure string aren't NULL

Comment: i have tried to lets say use the + and string . but it does not work , i did mine like  SELECT VVIndex, ('PD' + str([VIndex],len([VIndex]) + '0') AS VISTORID

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 you would do something like

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table 
 (   
   [VIndex] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
  ,[VISTORID]  AS ('PD' +  RIGHT('0000' + CAST([VIndex] AS VARCHAR(4)),4))  
                                                                      PERSISTED NOT NULL
 )
```

Comment: Thank you - it's a brilliant work around...